# Why use MultiParamTypeClasses in a MonadState

Tags: haskell

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    -- | Return the state from the internals of the monad.
    get :: m s
    get = state (\s -> (s, s))

    -- | Replace the state inside the monad.
    put :: s -> m ()
    put s = state (\_ -> ((), s))

    -- | Embed a simple state action into the monad.
    state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
    state f = do
      s <- get
      let ~(a, s') = f s
      put s'
      return a

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (MaybeT m) where...
```

Why does a instance of MonadState need a state and a monad, why not create a single parameter State class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the alternative you're suggesting. How would you write the type of `state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a` without both `m` and `s`?

Comment: let say we would start from `class MonadState s where...` and we just do `get :: s` and `put :: s -> ()` without putting s in a monad? Could it achieve a simpler state implementation where we do not have to worry about if it is a Maybe state or a Either state or a IO state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try and answer Gert's question in the comments, because it's a pretty different question.

The question is, why can we not just write

```
class State s where
   get :: s
   put :: s -> ()
```

Well, we could write this. But now the question is, what can we do with it? And the hard part is, if we have some code with `put x` and then later `get`, how do we link the `get` to the `put` so that the same value is returned as the one put in?

And the problem is, with just the types `()` and `s`, there is no way to link one to the other. You can try implementing it in various ways, but it won't work. There's just no way to carry the data from the `put` to the `get` (maybe someone can explain this better, but the best way to understand is to try writing it).

A Monad is not necessarily the only way to make operations linkable, but it is a way, because it has the `>>` operator to link two statements together:

```
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
```

so we can write

```
(put x) >> get
```

---

EDIT: Here is an example using [the `StateT` instance defined in the package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#MonadState)

```
foo :: StateT Int IO ()
foo = do
    put 3
    x <- get
    lift $ print x

main = evalStateT foo 0
```

Comment: can you add a IO example to your answer? Like `(put x) >> get >>= (\x -> print x)` or something?

Comment: @GertCuykens I can't think how to do it with `IO`; `IO` doesn't have a place to put state like `State` does. But I can add an example using `StateT` around `IO`.

Comment: @Owen - you can make an example using just `IO` with `IORef`.

Comment: @JohnL That's what I was hoping to do, but I couldn't figure it out. Care to give on?

Comment: @Owen not particularly, it looks harder than I thought.  Would you be interested in an unsound, not-working example?

Comment: @Owen: https://gist.github.com/3616775 - the test functions demonstrate some usage, and also show one manifestation of unsound-ness.  It also suffers from problems common with imperative code.  But otherwise I suppose it does work.

Answer (score 4):

You need some way of associating the type of the state to the type of the monad. `MultiParamTypeClasses` with `FunctionalDependencies` is one way. However, you can also do it using `TypeFamilies`.

```
class (Monad m) => MonadState m where
    type StateType m

    -- | Return the state from the internals of the monad.
    get :: m (StateType m)
    get = state (\s -> (s, s))

    -- | Replace the state inside the monad.
    put :: StateType m -> m ()
    put s = state (\_ -> ((), s))

    -- | Embed a simple state action into the monad.
    state :: (StateType m -> (a, StateType m)) -> m a
    state f = do
      s <- get
      let ~(a, s') = f s
      put s'
      return a

instance MonadState m => MonadState (MaybeT m) where
    type StateType (MaybeT m) = StateType m

    ...
```

This is the approach taken by the [monads-tf package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monads-tf/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html).

Comment: Note: `monads-tf` is basically retired. Originally, Ross split `mtl` up into `transformers` which was Haskell 98 and two packages `monads-tf` and `monads-fd` so people could choose which style they preferred. However, this was terrible as it split the community 3 ways, as `mtl`, `monads-tf` and `monads-fd` all used the same module names! The fix was to retire the old `mtl`, and make `monads-fd` into `mtl` and let `monads-tf` die. I wouldn't object to a package with the classes from `monads-tf` that was off to the side using different module names but, as it stands, it is downright detrimental.